# can NOT modified authenticators.xml to enable SSO

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I  got one err:  Error 405 -Method Not Allowed,
so, I want to enable SSO for IS,
then I modified <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml.

but, after I restarted IS server, authenticators.xml be recovered to original value.
Finally, Error 405 still be showed.

Can you tell me how to enable SSO for IS?

Thanks much!

henry

Comment: What is the version of IS that used? Do you want to set SAML2SSOAuthenticator's disable property = false?

Comment: Yes, I want change "SAML2SSOAuthenticator's disable property = false",  but after restart IS, it overwrote my change.    I downloaded IS projetc from here https://github.com/wso2/product-is, and build it and test it. I think its version should be V5.11

Comment: I added [admin_console.authenticator.saml_sso_authenticator]
enable=true  into deployment.toml, But, I can not open https://localhost:9443/carbon/, my browser always turn to "about:blank#blocked".  Then, I deleted  [admin_console.authenticator.saml_sso_authenticator]
enable=true, I can open https://localhost:9443/carbon/    normally

Answer (score 0):

If you have built the source code of the master branch, then it is `5.12.0-alpha10-SNAPSHOT` If you download the zip here https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0 it's IS-5.11.0

IS 5.9.0 onwards all configuration changes of XML files are maintained via a central location (deployment.toml). Therefore, in order to make your change navigate to `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` and add the following config. Then restart the server and check the relevant XML file. It should be changed.

```
[admin_console.authenticator.saml_sso_authenticator]
enable=true
```

Find more info about deployment.toml configuration model : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWvtcV1T94